# Importing Packages

Tags: go

I'm trying to learn Go and I'm writing some test programs, but I'm having a problem when importing my packages. I have this directory tree in my Go Workspace (inside src directory) ($GOPATH):

```
$GOPATH/src/gogoboy
│   main.go
│
├───cpu
│       flags.go
│       instructions.go
│       registers.go
│
└───memory
        memories.go
```

As you can see I've 2 packages at this moment: cpu and memory and this is my main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "gogoboy/cpu"
    "gogoboy/memory"
)

func main() {
    cpu.InitializeRegisters()
    memory.WriteRAM(0x00, 0xFF)
}
```

The problem is: The package cpu, at the same level of package memory, is imported correctly and I can use every cpu function but, the package memory raises the error:

```
.\main.go:10: undefined: memory.WriteRAM
```

I really can't understand what's happening, can anyone give a way to solve?

File memory/memories.go

```
package memory

const size uint16 = 0x2000

type Memories struct {
    RAM  [size]uint8
    VRAM [size]uint8
}

func (memory *Memories) WriteRAM(position uint16, value uint8) {
    memory.RAM[position] = value
}
```

Comment: The main function is calling the package level function `WriteRAM`.  There is no package level function with that name, but there is a method on `Memories` with that name.  It looks like you need to create a `Memories` value and call the method on that vaulue.

Comment: Let me see if I understand: The problem is a conflict of names? So I've to change the package name?

Comment: No not at all. There simpli _is_ no name memory.WriteRAM.

Comment: So... What I've to do to have the method memory.WriteRAM exported? Sorry guys, I'm really not understanding this problem...

Comment: You need to call the method on a `memories.Momeories` value and not as a function.  The method is already exported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not doing what you think you're doing; it looks like you WANT to call a method on a memory struct, but the compiler is looking for a function named WriteRam within the memory package because of how you're calling that method.

Look at your signature in memory.go:

```
func (memory *Memories) WriteRAM(position uint16, value uint8)
```

You have a receiver `func (memory *Memories)`. This means that in order to call this method, you need to have a memory.Memories variable declared somewhere.

I think you might want your main to look like this:

```
package main

import (
    "gogoboy/cpu"
    "gogoboy/memory"
)

func main() {
    cpu.InitializeRegisters()
    mem := memory.Memories{}
    mem.WriteRAM(0x00, 0xFF)
}
```

Comment: Ah! Now I Understand! Thank you William Taylor! The Package cpu has a method call InitializeRegisters where I put 0 on all values, the memory don't have a Initialization method.

Comment: Yup, that makes sense. Be sure to initialize your memory.Memories (I was just being lazy in my example)